# Reading a text file after updating it iteratively without stopping the program

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am reading a text file in my program and do some modifications in the file and then without stopping the program, I iteretively read the file and again and again, and each time I should be able to read the most recent version of the file. however, after first modification in the file, other times I am still getting that version of the file and seems other modifications are not applied.
Here is how I read the file:

```
  public static Map<String, Float> readOwnersBiasFile() throws IOException {
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("ownersBias.txt");
Map<String, Float> ownerBiasMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();
//Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] var = line.split("\\^");
        ownerBiasMap.put(var[0], Float.valueOf(var[1]));
    }

    br.close();
    return ownerBiasMap;
```

}
and here is how I store my modifications:

```
  public static void storeOwnersUtilityMap(Map<String, Float> ownersUtilityMap) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("ownersBias.txt");
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String s;

        String[] var;
        if (bufferedReader.readLine() == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : ownersUtilityMap.entrySet()) {
                lines.add(entry.getKey().concat("^").concat(String.valueOf(entry.getValue())));
            }
        } else
            while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                var = s.split("\\^");
                if (ownersUtilityMap.containsKey(var[0]))
                    s = var[0].concat("^").concat(String.valueOf(ownersUtilityMap.get(var[0])));
                lines.add(s);
            }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStreamReader);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileInputStream);
    }

    fileWriter(lines, "ownersBias.txt");
```

}

```
    private static void fileWriter(List<String> list, String fileName) throws IOException {
    File fout = new File(fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        bw.write(iterator.next());
        bw.newLine();
    }

    bw.close();
}
```

And in my main method I have a loop that do some stuff along with reading and modification of the text file.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TasteException {
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
map= readOwnersBiasFile();
do some stuff;
storeOwnersUtilityMap(map);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you give an actual code that compiles ? It seems you've merged two methods

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: Instead of repeatedly reading the file then trying to write back to the file, you should just use a RandomAccessFile to append to the file.

Comment: I am modifying some records. it's not just adding some lines to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not be necessary to close the programs between re-reads, I've written programs that would read the same file and get any external changes.  So that part I know works.

Now the top method readOwnersBiasFile() does not seem to close everything explicitly; I see the BufferedReader closed, but not the InputStreamReader or FileInputStream.  When leaving the method, the objects have no references and therefore garbage collection should find them, timing could be an issue.  I recommend try-with-resources for anything Closeable.

Operating system might cause differences, however, especially if you're both writing and reading from the same JVM.  For example, in Windows you can't delete/move/rename an already open file, but *nix you can.  What I don't know (partially because I don't know you're runtime platform) is whether the JVM is being tricky with file handles and tries to reuse in such a way that the changes aren't flushed from the write before things are read or whatever.

If might be worthwhile examining properties on your File object, make sure you see size changes or changed last modified dates or whatever that might indicate you're actually picking up the differences.

I also can't tell anything about the order you're calling things (in particular the first two blocks of code), whether you're doing things multithreaded or what.  Open/reading/writing in a multithreaded environment might be problematic